# Servlet not loading in the browser

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've just started working on servlets and i'm a newbie.
I have developed a html page with a drop-down menu from which the user can select the color of beer and there is a submit button which invokes the servlet.Here is the html code for it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Beer Selection</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Beer Selection Page</h2>
<p>Select beer charecteristics:</p>
<hr>
<form method="POST" action="SelectBeer.do">
    <b>Color :</b><!--Keeping it outside the form unnecessarily creates a line break between color and Drop-down menu-->
    <select name="color">
        <option>Light</option>
        <option>Brown</option>
        <option>Amber</option>
        <option>Dark</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created the following deployment descriptor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyBeer</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyBeer</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have also successfully compiled the BeerSelect.java servlet whose code is given below

```
package com.example.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");
    String c=request.getParameter("color");
    out.println("<br>Got Beer color"+c);
}
}
```

I am using tomcat 7.0.21 and i have created the directories as follows:
     tomcat/webapps/learning/Beer-v1/form.html  and
     tomcat/webapps/learning/Beer-v1/WEB-INF/web.xml   and
     tomcat/webapps/learning/Beer-v1/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/web/BeerSelect.class
(learning is just a folder in which i keep all my small servlet and jsp projects in webapps
Inside learning i've my different project such as Beer-v1,DateDisplay,HotelMgmt,etc.)

Now when i run the form.html inside tomcat it is properly displayed but when i click on submit it shows

```
HTTP Status 404 - /learning/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do

type Status report

message /learning/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do

description The requested resource (/learning/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.21
```

what am i doing wrong .Please help.

Comment: I cant seem to see any error. Have you tried restarting your server? When editing config files and creating new classes, you'll need to restart your server.

Comment: I have restarted nearly 6-7 times but still getting the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you have `Beer-v1` as a direct subfolder of the Tomcat's `webapp` folder.
Then try to access [tomcaturl]/Beer-v1/[yourhtmlform].html.

Because you mapped your servlet to the context root (which is `/`), there is no mapping for a `/learning/Beer-v1/SelectBeer.do`.

IMHO it is not a very good idea to have your workspace folder structure *inside* Tomcat's webapp folder. This is a special folder for deployed webapps, and Tomcat is expecting a kind of standard structure for this folder (WEB-INF inside root directory, for example).

I think it is better to use Eclipse or something that deploys your application (from your filesystem) to Tomcat automatically. This way you can have your workspace managed however you want.

Eclipse maintains a so called 'workspace' where it stores all projects that you create with it. The first time you start Eclipse it will ask you which folder to use as workspace. You could then name your 'learning' folder as you use it at the moment.

When you add a server execution environment to Eclipse (e.g. a Tomcat installation), you can configure how Eclipse deploys. The default configuration is to copy the webapp to a Eclipse specific workspace subfolder.

Comment: How eclipse works??
We create a workspace where our files are saved .Does it deploy the apps in webapp permanently(thus creating 2 copies one in workspace and one in tomcat/webapps ) or does it deploys them temporarily (thus keeping a single copy)??

OR Is Eclipse able to maintain folder hierarchies as  i was trying to do??
JUST NEED A SMALL OVERVIEW .

Answer (score 1):

try adding a slash in you form action

```
action="SelectBeer.do"
```

to

```
action="/SelectBeer.do"
```

Comment: Hey Russell Gutierrez,the method you suggested didn't work but surprisingly now i'm not getting any error message but instead i'm getting a blank page.
Mulmoth suggested a way which works but i want to keep the "Learning" folder if it is possible and still make the app run .What changes can i made in deployment descriptor web.xml